# Adding JComponents dynamically to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jcomponent

I'm doing a project using java swings. In my project I need to have jTextfield and jTextarea dynamically to a jFrame.

Means ,if a j button is clicked than some set of JComponents need to be placed in that jFrame.

Comment: If do you need more information about this problem ask me...

Answer (score 3):

> Try to use jframe.repaint() in your button actionPerformed function or
>   jframe.revalidate() or both of it.

Comment: Thanks I'll try your suggestion

Comment: 1+ The basic code is `revalidate()` (to invoke the layout manager) followed by `repaint()` to paint the components at their new size/location.